# Charles Bukowski's "best dick"

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, ambiguity

I am reading Charles Bukowski's [Pulp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_%28novel%29) and as non-native English speaker I am finding decoding certain expressions challenging. For example the main character, Nicky Belane, often refers to himself using the phrase "best dick (in L.A.)". Given the context, it seems to me the word "dick" is here used as for "detective", but I couldn't find this meaning anywhere else - in other books or on the internet.

One example:

> The next day I took a chance and went back to the office. After all, what's a dick without a office? (p. 16)

Or:

> 'Hey,' said McKelvey, 'where'd you get that damned thing?'
>   'A dick without a gat is like a tomcat with a rubber. Or like a clock without hands.' (p. 13)

Comment: I'd have thought this definition would be in *every* half-way credible dictionary. It's in [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dick), anyway, and I don't see why ELU needs to confirm the meaning.

Comment: "A dick without a gat" also means a penis without a vagina. Look up slang for *dick* next time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA. While you are at it, look up "gat" too. It is a kind of gun.

Comment: @fdb I didn't post the question. The [double entendre](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20entendre) was pretty obvious even to me.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, I believe the sentence in dispute can be interpreted as follows:  A detective without a gun is like a promiscuous cat wearing a condom, or a clock that doesn't tell the time.  (It can't accomplish its purpose.)

Comment: Yes, "dick" is short for "detective", probably since the 20s or 30s.  And, yes, there is often a double entendre.  (It would be an interesting investigation for some word dick to determine when "dick" came to mean "penis".)

Comment: its from pronouncing detective 'dick-tective''

Comment: Note also that his detective's name, Nicky Belane, is an obvious rhyme with Mickey Spillane, the archetypal writer of pulp detective fiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hardboiled detective stories and noir fiction, *dick* is a well-established synonym for ***detective*** (particularly ***private*** detective, as opposed to law enforcement).

For example, from the Miskatonic [Glossary of Hardboiled Slang](https://www.miskatonic.org/slang.html):

> **Dick**: *Detective* (usually qualified with “*private*” if not a policeman)

Comment: Also: [gumshoe, flatfoot, tec.](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gumshoe)